# Refractive index from absorbance, transmittance or reflectance spectra of thin film, knowing its thickness

Tags: optics, material-science, refraction, spectroscopy

I have absorbance (Abs), reflectance (R%) and transmittance (T%) data of TiO2 deposited thin film on FTO glass substrate. The data was collected using UV-Vis spectrophotometer. Also, I know the thickness of the thin film and substratre.

How to calculate refractive index n of TiO2 from this?

If you know a simple way, kindly suggest how to proceed.

Comment: In a prior post you said that you tried to calculate the refractive index using the magnitudes of A,T,R but failed. If your light source were a coherent one then Fresnel's equation would work when taking into account both the magnitude and phase of A,T,R; the magnitudes themselves are not enough. I have not seen a formula that has averaged the phase out in Fresnel's but you may try to run a few thousand simulations and see if it is stable enough to use it that way. Just a thought.

Comment: you can also contact https://www.jasco-global.com/product-spectroscopy/uv-visible-nir/ with application questions

Comment: @hyportnex thank you so much , but what to do with JASCO text box? It prevented me to contact them..

Comment: check the owner's manual how to contact them